# calculate squares root of $-1+i\sqrt{3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

So what I did is:

1. $z^2=-1+i\sqrt{3}$
2. $z=\left| z \right|e^{i\theta}$
3. $\left| z\right|=\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{3}^2}=\sqrt{4}=2$
4. $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z)}{\operatorname{Im}(z)}\right)=\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})=60°=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Finally I found: $\sqrt{-1+i\sqrt{3}}=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$

But the correction give: $-1-i\sqrt{3}=2e^{-2i\frac{\pi}{3}}$

Where does that $-2$ comes from ?

Comment: It's $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\operatorname{Im}(z)/\operatorname{Re}(z))$, not $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\operatorname{Re}(z)/\operatorname{Im}(z))$ as you wrote.  And even that only works when $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$, which is not the case here, so you have to add $\pi$ to get a correct value of $\theta$. (Personally, I prefer $\theta=\pm\cos^{-1}(\operatorname{Re}(z)/|z|)$, where the $\pm$ is given by the sign of $\operatorname{Im}(z)$; that way you get $-\pi<\theta\leq\pi$ and no worries about division by zero along the way.)

Answer (score 1):

If you write $z=-1+\sqrt 3\,i$ as $2e^{i\theta}$, then$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=-\sqrt3,$$and so, since $\sin\theta<0$, you can take $\theta=\frac{2\pi}3$ (note that $\theta\ne\arctan\left(\frac{\operatorname{Im}z}{\operatorname{Re}z}\right)$). So, a square root of $-1+\sqrt3 i$ is$$\sqrt2e^{\pi i/3}=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\sqrt{\frac32}\,i.$$

Comment: You're welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming square root here means principal square root, note that for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$,

$$\sqrt {r(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)}=\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt re^{i\frac{\theta}{2} } =\sqrt {r}\left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right).$$

Visualize $-1+i\sqrt 3$ as the vector $(-1,\sqrt 3)$ in the complex plane and realize this vector has magnitude $r=\sqrt {(-1)^2+(\sqrt 3)^2}=2$ and angle (measured counterclockwise from the positive real axis) of $\theta=2\pi/3$. Thus,

$$\sqrt {-1+i\sqrt 3}=\sqrt{2e^{i2\pi/3}}=\sqrt 2e^{i\pi/3 } =\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+i\sqrt\frac{3}{2}.$$